# Is it possible to set condition to the values of the column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I need to **set limit to the values of the column**. For example, I have a column as TEST_COLUMN with INTEGER data type. I need to set the condition that **the column should only accepts the values between
1-4.(it should not be more than 4 and less than 1)** Is it possible in postgress?

Thanks in Advance.

I may handle it in the code level but **is there is a way to do it in Database level**.

Comment: The requirement "*less than 1*" contradicts the requirement "*between 1 and 4*"

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't mean "postgresql 9.4" in your tags - that version is VERY old.

What you are after is a "CHECK constraint".

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-constraints.html

You use it something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    ...
    my_column int NOT NULL CHECK (my_column BETWEEN 1 AND 4)
    ...
)
```

For PostgreSQL at least, the check shouldn't rely on running a query, just accessing columns from the row you are inserting or updating.

Comment: If the above successfully answered your question then please accept it. This helps future questions with the same/similar issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave an answered question in an unanswered state.